# When I try to install ruby 3.3.0-dev with rbenv it says BUILD FAILED, how do I fix this?

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, rubygems, debian, rbenv

```
$ rbenv install 3.3.0-dev

To follow progress, use 'tail -f /tmp/ruby-build.20230327204531.21780.log' or pass --verbose
Cloning https://github.com/ruby/ruby.git...
Installing ruby-master...

BUILD FAILED (Debian 10 using ruby-build 20230309-1-gf3c1ccc)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20230327204531.21780.nBIyRT
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20230327204531.21780.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:547:in `block (2 levels) in verify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/tar_reader.rb:29:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:546:in `block in verify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `open'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package/file_source.rb:30:in `with_read_io'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:545:in `verify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/package.rb:526:in `spec'
    from /tmp/ruby-build.20230327204531.21780.nBIyRT/ruby-master/tool/lib/bundled_gem.rb:13:in `unpack'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
make: *** [defs/gmake.mk:333: .bundle/gems/minitest-5.18.0] Error 1
```

I tried to install Ruby 3.3.0-dev on top of 2.5.5
I expected it to install Ruby 3.3.0-dev over 2.5.5
What actually resulted was a "BUILD FAIL